# Do only tagged people get notified of comment?

Tags: support, tags, comments

I commented on someone's answer to get more information about it but I wanted two people to get notified about to comment. One of them was the writer of the answer and then another person who also commented.

Since we can only tag one person to the comment by doing `@userName`, does that mean that the write of the answer won't get notified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the person who posted the question or answer will always be notified that a comment was posted. Using `@` for the original poster is unnecessary.

Comment: So since I want to tag 2 people, one of them being the write of the answer and the other being another commenter, I just need to use `@` for the other commenter and the writer will get notified still.

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal Yep, the OP will still get a notification.